# Is there a way to configure Inkscape to use whole numbers in the interface rather than decimals for common properties?

Tags: gui, inkscape

I don't need that much precision most the time and I prefer, for example, to see 100,100 for x,y or width,height values rather than 100.224,100.082.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be no option currently available to do this. As [prokoudine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110044/is-there-a-way-to-configure-inkscape-to-use-whole-numbers-in-the-interface-rathe#comment131778_111496) suggested, I have opened a feature request. It can be tracked here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/951655

Answer (score 3):

You can try to configure Inkscape for saving no decimals whatsoever.

1. File > Inkscape Preferences > SVG Output
2. Numeric precision > set to 0

Comment: Sorry, the question was a bit ambiguous. I am referring specifically to the main user interface when editing an image. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: No, that's not possible, sorry. You can file it to the bug tracker as a feature request. But if this is about getting pixel crisp images, I recommend the Pixelsnap extension available since 0.48 or so. It adjusts selected objects in a way that they align to pixel grid.

Comment: Your answer was what I was looking for as I want to stop inscape from giving me values with decimals in SVG. With Numeric precision set to  3 I get close enough to what I want but it will still give me things like 32.5 when I would really just like 32.

Comment: It seems that the Netscape file menu has changed somewhat since 2012 and the path to "SVG Output" is no longer File > Inkscape Preferences > SVG Output but
Edit > Preferences > SVG Output
(Shortcut to preferences is Shift+Control+P)